# I can not install wine -1.6

Tags: installation, wine, package-management, tar

I am using tar file. I am extracting using tar xvjf filename then I am doing ./configure
and getting error to install package fetch. Now what to do?

Comment: yes but i have mentioned that i have downloaded flex.deb file..then what to do..with out any internet connection in ubuntu

Comment: Flex is a patch for Android device.  Your question is about installing Wine?  If you want to install Wine, just see the additions in your other question.

Comment: sorry sir my mistake..but I am going to follow second anwser let see what happen

Comment: what ubuntu you were using, 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04?

Comment: I think version doesn't matter in this scenario